# how can i store selected rows of tableview in nsuserdefaults in swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode

I have one tableview in which numbers of rows and in each rows add button and from that i am selecting some and then that selected buttons of rows i want to store in nsuserdefaults in swift 3.

Comment: Post the code you have tried?

Comment: i'm new for ios so now i'm just trying for this,i had simple tableview and in that putted two buttons add and delete in each row ,this idea is just like cart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saving all the rows that have been selected, can be solved like this:

```
var selectedRows: [Int] = []

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.selectedRows.append(indexPath.row)

    UserDefaults.standard.set(selectedRows, forKey: "selectedRows")
}
```

Later, use

```
if let selectedRows = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "selectedRows") as? [Int] {
    // Do what you want with the selectedRows
}
```

if you want to get all of the selectedRows back