# Swift - Allow ONLY one checkbox selected inside a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsuserdefaults, checkmark

I am trying to achieve to make my **TableView** only accept one checkbox per cell.

I have used [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51923705/5107075) to save User Defaults for the checkmarks which works fine but it allow multiple selections.

I have tried so many solutions on Stack overflow but since this is formatted a little different I was unable to use those solutions.

Things I have tried which did not work:

**Tried setting the accessory type to none at the `didDeselectRowAt`**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .none 
}
```

**Tried setting the table view to not allow multiple selections on the `viewDidNotLoad`**

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    tableViewName.allowsMultipleSelection = false
}
```

Based the solution I linked, how would I go to only allow a single selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the solution you have linked there is this code in the 'didSelect' function

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) 
{
    if selectedRows.contains(indexPath.row) {
        self.selectedRows = selectedRows.filter{$0 != indexPath.row}
    }else{
        self.selectedRows.append(indexPath.row)
    }
    UserDefaults.standard.set(selectedRows, forKey: "selectedRows")
}
```

If you only want a single checkbox to be selected then you only want a single entity saved in your `selectedRows` object.  Change the above code to:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) 
{
    self.selectedRows = [indexPath.row]

    UserDefaults.standard.set(selectedRows, forKey: "selectedRows")
}
```

Then every time a checkbox is selected it will clear out all the other selected checkboxes and select only the checkbox you just clicked.